# Lazy loading inside material-ui Table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, lazy-loading

In my `react` application, I'm trying to use `react-lazy-load` npm library inside my `TableBody` from `material-ui`.
I've also tried the `react-infinite-scroll-component`, but in both of them I get this error:

```
<tr> cannot appear as a child of <div>
```

which makes sense.
Is there any way how can I use lazy loading in my table?

```
import LazyLoad from 'react-lazy-load';
import {Table, TableBody, TableCell, TableHead, TableRow} from '@material-ui/core';

<TableBody>
 {users.map(user,i) =>
      <LazyLoad  key{i} height={68} offset={20}
        <UserItem   (**returns TableRow**)
        (UserItem props)
        >
     </LazyLoad>
</TableBody>
```

Comment: What is your goal with LazyLoad ? Perhaps  what you're looking for is [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized), [virtualized table](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#virtualized-table).

Comment: @mtx Yes. I'm trying to make the material table virtualized, but their example with react-virtuarlized kinda complex, is there another way maybe?